# Laptop boots to Grub

Tags: boot, grub2

Upon booting up my laptop, grub always opens up. I then proceed by typing "Exit" and the computer boots up normally.

Comment: Do your system write any output before the grub prompt ?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Only Grub appears after a second or two after pressing the power button.